# How to increase element in a set?

Tags: c++, set, immutability, mutability

I'm trying to decrease the largest numbers until I run out of m to decrease. For that I thought the set was the best solution, so I tried it. It didn't work. This is the first time I run into an error like this. Is there any way to change elements "mutability". If you have any advice for a better solution feel free to answer.

```
set<pair<float, long int>> t;
    long unsigned n, m;
    scanf("%lu%lu", &n, &m);
    for (long unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float p;
        scanf("%f", &p);
        t.insert({p, 1});
    }
    m -= n;
    while (m)
    {
        (*--t.end()).second++;
        (*--t.end()).first *= ((*--t.end()).second - 1) / (*--t.end()).second;
        m--;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to change elements "mutability"

Not the elements of a set. They are always const. You may not modify them.

What you can do instead is make a copy of the element, erase the element from the set, and insert a modified value.

P.S. Instead of `(*--t.end())`, use `t.back()`

Comment: Is there any way to go around insertion, because the complexity of it is log(n)? This needs to work for pretty large numbers under a second.

Comment: @Vojin You could use a better data structure than a set. The high level structure that you need is a priority queue. I don't think `std::priority_queue` guarantees better than logarithmic decrease-key operation, but I think a priority queue can be implemented with constant decrease-key.

Comment: @eerorika That's just what I was looking for. Thank you.